# Array destructoring in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented a hook that returns an array with two elements like below.

```
export function useSearchParams() {
 ..
 ../
return [searchParams, setSearchParams];
```

}

I only need to access this `setSearchParams` element in my component.

```
 const [{},setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

This throws an es-lint warning when I add `{}` for the first parameter. What is the best practice on this? If I only want to access the second parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const [,setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

Example:

```js
let arr = [1,3];
let [,ans] = arr;

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use

```
const [,setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```